# assigned <= or == or >== to variables python django

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to assign operators to variables?
I have function

```
def get_age(age=0, year_level_from=0, year_level_to=0):
    overall = []
    for level in range(year_level_from, year_level_to):
        if age <= 11:
           operator = <=
        else:
           operator = >=
        male_count = len([
            info for info in queryset
            if info.age **operator** age
            if info.gender == 'male'
            if info.year_level == level
        ])
        overall.append(male_count)
```

I want to declare like get_age(age=11, year_level_from=1, year_level_to=7) if this is possible so this function have the ability to choose those age with that condition I want to get. thanks in advance

Comment: create function ie. `def ge(a,b): return a>= b` and then you can assign `operator =   ge` and use `operator( info.age,  age)`

Comment: instead of there `if` should be `if ... and ... and ...`

Comment: @furas That’s in a list comprehension and works just fine that way.

Comment: you can use: `(age <= 11) == (info.age<=age)`, no need to change the operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html) library: (You'll obviously have to use a different name than `operator` for the variable in that case!) Usage would be like the below (only the significant lines shown to give you the idea):

```
import operator
...
if age <= 11
    compare_function = operator.le
...
[...
if compare_function(info.age, age):
...]
```

Or if you don't want to import that for some reason, it's not too hard to define these on your own with lambda functions, eg:

```
if age <= 11:
    operator = lambda a, b: a <= b
```

And use as

```
if operator(info.age, age)
```

inside your list comprehension.